# Why does a September month add five hours to my time difference method?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm making  a simple shift logger and salary calculator to practice Swift, but for some reason this one method adds five hours to any date except August.

```
func getShift () -> Shift{
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd w W HH:mm"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    let from:NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(self.fromDate)!
    let to:NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(self.toDate)!
    let length:Double = to.timeIntervalSinceDate(from) as Double / 60

    let newShift = Shift(from:from,to:to,length:length)
    return newShift
}
```

I use the length variable in this method to calculate salary

```
func calcSalary(ub: Bool){
    if (ub){

    } else {
        let hours = length/60
        let minutes = (length%60) * (5/3)
        let billable = hours + minutes/10
        self.salary = billable*hour
        println("Got paid \(self.salary) for \(billable) hours times \(hour) from \(fromDate) to \(toDate)")
        //Got paid 792.05 for 7.0 hours times 113.15 from 2014-08-21 13:00:00 +0000 to 2014-08-21 20:00:00 +0000
        //Got paid 1018.35 for 9.0 hours times 113.15 from 2014-08-23 08:00:00 +0000 to 2014-08-23 17:00:00 +0000
        //Got paid 961.775 for 8.5 hours times 113.15 from 2014-08-24 11:15:00 +0000 to 2014-08-24 14:45:00 +0000
        //Got paid 1527.525 for 13.5 hours times 113.15 from 2014-09-04 13:00:00 +0000 to 2014-09-04 21:30:00 +0000
        //Got paid 1074.925 for 9.5 hours times 113.15 from 2014-09-05 12:00:00 +0000 to 2014-09-05 16:30:00 +0000

    }
}
```

As you can see at the bottom two dates, it adds five hours. What is even weirder, I use the same shift.length variable in my interface, and there it is correct. 
[image]

I'm really bad at working with dates (and Swift), can anyone spot out the fault in my methods?

---

**EDIT**
fromDate and toDate resides in my Shift class, as shown here:

```
class Shift {
var fromDate : NSDate
var toDate : NSDate
var length : Double //In Minutes
var salary : Double = Double()

let hour = 113.15
let etter18hverdag = 22
let etter21hverdag = 45
let helligdag = 90
let helgEtter13 = 45
let helgEtter16 = 90 //HUSK AT PAUSE FINNES

init (from : NSDate, to : NSDate, length:Double){
    self.fromDate = from
    self.toDate = to
    self.length = length

}
func calcSalary(ub: Bool){
    if (ub){

    } else {
        let hours = length/60
        let minutes = (length%60) * (5/3)
        let billable = hours + minutes/10
        self.salary = billable*hour
        println("Got paid \(self.salary) for \(billable) hours times \(hour) from \(fromDate) to \(toDate)")
        //Got paid 792.05 for 7.0 hours times 113.15 from 2014-08-21 13:00:00 +0000 to 2014-08-21 20:00:00 +0000
        //Got paid 1018.35 for 9.0 hours times 113.15 from 2014-08-23 08:00:00 +0000 to 2014-08-23 17:00:00 +0000
        //Got paid 961.775 for 8.5 hours times 113.15 from 2014-08-24 11:15:00 +0000 to 2014-08-24 14:45:00 +0000
        //Got paid 1527.525 for 13.5 hours times 113.15 from 2014-09-04 13:00:00 +0000 to 2014-09-04 21:30:00 +0000
        //Got paid 1074.925 for 9.5 hours times 113.15 from 2014-09-05 12:00:00 +0000 to 2014-09-05 16:30:00 +0000

    }
}
}
```

The toDate and fromDate comes from the first method in my post, getShift(). They are dates collected from a date picker wheel. Code for that shown here. from and toDate in the first method are from my NSManagedObject class, saved from the below code.

```
@IBAction func donePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    //ÅR-MÅNED-DAG (2011-12-29) UKE I ÅR  UKE I MND (27 3)
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd w W HH:mm"
    dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateStringFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    var appDel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var  context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let newShift = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Shifts", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newShift.setValue("\(dateStringFormatter.stringFromDate(fromDate))", forKey: "fromDate")
    newShift.setValue("\(dateStringFormatter.stringFromDate(toDate))", forKey: "toDate")

    context.save(nil)
```

Comment: What do you have in self.fromDate and self.toDate variables?

Comment: @paiv Look at updated post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with September - the value for August24th also has 5 hours added as well.  Rather, the problem is where you have half-hour periods.

That in turn us because of this section of code :

```
    let hours = length/60
    let minutes = (length%60) * (5/3)
    let billable = hours + minutes/10
```

Hours is OK (or rather would be if 'length' was an int rather than a double) - but what on earth is the 5/3 factor for minutes ?  And then you add minutes/10 to hours ??? Eg. If You have 50 minutes, do you REALLY want to add 5 to the hours ;)

Rather, you could do either of the following :
Since 'length' is the number of minutes as a double, then simply :

```
    let billable = length/60.0
```

Alternatively, if you want to calculate via minutes,

```
    let hours = length/60
    let minutes = (length%60)
    let billable = hours + minutes/60.0
```

And I'd really recommend having length as an integer :)

Comment: MacOS X and iOS _always_ store times using double meaning seconds. If you store times with a different meaning than seconds, you should always use a variable name with the unit. Like lengthInMinutes or billableHours.

Comment: AHHHH of course! How stupid of me, I was messing around with this very bit, converting time to base10 before I went to lunch. Thanks a lot for saving my brain cells before I had to facedesk even more.